# No need for bias term if data is standardised? Linear classification models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-model, bias, perceptron

For linear classification models, e.g. perceptron, bias term allows to move separating hyperplane away from origin. If data is scattered around the zero does that mean that we don't need bias term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no. There is no guarantee that the separating hyperplane is passing through the data mean. Consider the following case: The data has been standardized, but you still need the bias term to get an optimal separating hyperplane:

[image]